# SDL Mixer Load_Mus crashes program

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I've been working on my first SDL game and adding sound effects went without a hitch. However as soon as I tried adding music, Mix_LoadMus() crashes the program.

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) !=0)
    std::cout<<"SDL_INIT failed\n"<<SDL_GetError()<<std::endl;

if( Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_OGG | MIX_INIT_MOD | MIX_INIT_FLAC | MIX_INIT_MP3) !=0 )
    std::cout<< "SDL_mixer could not initialize! SDL_mixer Error\n"<<Mix_GetError()<<std::endl;


if( Mix_OpenAudio( 44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048 ) < 0 )
    std::cout<< "SDL_mixer could not open audio! SDL_mixer Error\n"<<Mix_GetError()<<std::endl;

Mix_Music *music = Mix_LoadMUS("music.wav");
if( music == NULL )
    std::cout<<"Failed to load music! SDL_mixer Error\n"<<Mix_GetError()<<std::endl;
```

This crashes without any output. 
Heres the backtrace:

```
RaiseException()
SDL_LogCritical()
SDL_LogCritical()
SDL_LogCritical()
KERENEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

My assumption is that something goes horribly wrong when retrieving the file but I have no idea how to go about correcting it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where's your `Mix_Init()` call?

Comment: forgot to add it to test code my bad. program still crashes though.

Comment: Did you get it working? Having same kind of problem.